# SSRS: Filter 1 datasets with the value from the second dataset

Tags: sql, function, reporting-services, visual-studio-2015

I have two datasets from 2 different data Sources. 
1- M
2- C
this two datasets have a column name ID. I want to filter M dataset with the id's in C datasets
can you help?

Comment: dataset with another dataset????

Comment: I think you may be looking for a subquery in your SQL Statement.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use one dataset to filter another dataset.  The only way you could get approximate functionality would be to either populate a multi-value parameter with one dataset and then use that as an exclusion criteria in the second, or to have a `lookup` filter on all your report items.

Both of these options will run very badly.

I would recommend looking at why you need to filter the results from one data source with the results of another, as this reeks of either bad design or misunderstanding requirements.